# Can we read file from mount drives in django apache

Tags: django, apache, python-2.6

I am writing one function to get file size in django application.

Django application we are running through apache server.

File is located in some other location. We are getting that file through mounted path.

Code is as follows,

```
import os
filePath = '/mnt/file.html'
size = flaot(os.stat(filePath))
```

If I run django server through runserver command then it is working fine.

If I run djnago server through apache then it will not work.

If the file is in the same location then it will work through both way(with apache and without apache)Ex. filePath = '/home' OR '/root' OR any location from same machine

What will the another way to get the file size from mounted path through django-apache

Please Help.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apache probably is running under a user that lacks permission to access `/mnt`.

For example, on Ubuntu apache runs under `www-data`. In order to confirm this, try to give read/execute permission on the `/mnt` folder to the user running apache or execute runserver under the same user running apache and see if you get the same error.

If you don't know which user is running apache, try:

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

If the apache server executable is not named apache or apache2 (for example, in some linux distros it is named httpd) then replace apache with the executable name in the above command.

Lets say the user running apache is www-data:

```
su - www-data -c "cat /mnt/file.html"
```

If the issue is related to permissions, you should see an error message telling you what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with directory/file permissions and/or privileges of the user that the process uses.

When you run the Django server, it runs under your username, and most probably your user has access to the places that hold your files; but when it runs behind Apache, it runs as Apache or www-data users, which doesn't have access to those places.

Solution: Either you change the directory permissions, add the Apache users to the group of users allowed to access this directory(s), or make the Apache user the owner of this directory(s), choose whichever that suits you!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't got permission/ownership for apache user so I not test.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; You say you are not allowed to set permissions?